# JayData reading from OData controller throws ODataContentTypeException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, jaydata

I have an ODataController which seems to work fine if I just do a GET through my browser.  But when I use JayData to read I get a 500 back. I can see GetItems() being called in my ODataController and it returns a valid list of Items. I but I am seeing a handful of ODataContentTypeException exceptions being thrown which have the follwing message:

> Additional information: A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=feed, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose, application/json' matches the content type 'application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8'.

Then

> Additional information: A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/atom+xml;type=feed, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose, application/json' matches the content type 'application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8'.

Then

> Additional information: A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/xml, application/json;odata=verbose, application/json' matches the content type 'application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8'.

And lastly

> Additional information: A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/xml, application/json;odata=verbose, application/json' matches the content type 'application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8'.

I am assuming these are the cause of the 500 I am getting back, but there doesnt' seem to be a way to be sure.
According to Chrome, the request being sent is requesting the following:

> Accept:application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

An empty response with a 500 error is all that is received back. Anyone else having this trouble?

> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-CA;q=0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this solution to make sense more info is needed:  Using MVC5, with WebAPI 2.0, and the OData nuget package version 5.0

For some reason JayData is trying to use OData v2. So to fix it, I dug through the source code and found that you can specify V3.

Change the configuration of your context to include maxDataServiceVersion: "3.0".

From this:

```
dbContext = new MyEntities({ name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: '/odata' }));
```

To this:

```
dbContext = new MyEntities({ name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: '/odata', maxDataServiceVersion: '3.0' }));
```

And that works for me.

It would be nice if JayStack would document the configuration options available.

Comment: I should like to upvote you a thousand times more, but alas good sir I am permitted but one